# Speed limit of information transfer ($c$) & limiting size of observable universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space

There can be places in the universe where the speed of space expansion is greater than $c$. So, according to relativity, from those places we can't get any information. Doesn't this concept put a limit on the observable universe?

Well, what I want to really ask is if in the current up-to-date cosmological model and infos, a limit is really possible? Or, the universe will stop accelerating or start shrinking, the limiting size will never be attained?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cosmological_horizons

Comment: I know you can mathematically determine the horizons. But my question if the universe would reach the expansion rate greater than c and the limiting size.

Comment: I am not sure what is the question, as the article says, there are "right now" galaxies that are moving at speeds larger than c relative to us

Comment: Please see this [Q&A](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19909/10589). There are galaxies that were always receding away from us faster than the speed of light and yet we see them (the farther they are, the faster they're receding away). The current cosmological models, based on the measurements of Dark Energy proportions, favor the [Heat Death of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe) in an ever expanding space.